# Using jq, how to replace the value of particular key?

Tags: replace, json, jq

How to replace the `xxx` with `yyy`?

```json
{
    "spec": {
        "template": {
            "spec": {
                "containers": [{
                    "args": [
                        "proxy",
                        "router",
                        "--domain",
                        "$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local",
                        "--proxyLogLevel=warning",
                        "--proxyComponentLogLevel=misc:error",
                        "--log_output_level=default:info",
                        "--serviceCluster",
                        "istio-ingressgateway"
                    ],
                    "env": [{
                            "name": "JWT_POLICY",
                            "value": "third-party-jwt"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "ISTIO_META_OWNER",
                            "value": "kubernetes://apis/apps/v1/namespaces/istio-system/deployments/xxx"
                        }
                    ]
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you can specifically change the `.spec.template.spec.containers[].env[].value` for the *ISTIO_META_OWNER* using `|= sub()`

**Here's how the substitution looked applied below:**

```
jq -r '.spec.template.spec.containers[].env[] | (select(.name=="ISTIO_META_OWNER") |.value |= sub("xxx$"; "yyy"))' kubernetes_spec_example.json
```

Which results in the following:

```
{
  "name": "ISTIO_META_OWNER",
  "value": "kubernetes://apis/apps/v1/namespaces/istio-system/deployments/yyy"
}
```

Comment: @souji bala did the answer work for you?

Comment: This seems to have deleted most of the data too.

Comment: nothing was deleted...I specifically filtered for the `.env.value` for OP's question to demonstrate how to change the value of that key. For the novice jq person, I thought it would be helpful to hone in on that specifically.

Answer (score 4):

The following uses `jq` to replace the `xxx` with `yyy` at the end of the `value` node corresponding to the `name` node with value `ISTIO_META_OWNER`.

```bsh
jq '( .spec.template.spec.containers[].env[] | select(.name == "ISTIO_META_OWNER").value ) |= sub("xxx$"; "yyy")' file.json
```

This uses `sub("xxx$"; "yyy")` to substitute the text that matches `xxx$` in the value with `yyy`.  The `$` is a regular expression anchor that anchors the expression to the end of the string.

The result is

```json
{
  "spec": {
    "template": {
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "args": [
              "proxy",
              "router",
              "--domain",
              "$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local",
              "--proxyLogLevel=warning",
              "--proxyComponentLogLevel=misc:error",
              "--log_output_level=default:info",
              "--serviceCluster",
              "istio-ingressgateway"
            ],
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "JWT_POLICY",
                "value": "third-party-jwt"
              },
              {
                "name": "ISTIO_META_OWNER",
                "value": "kubernetes://apis/apps/v1/namespaces/istio-system/deployments/yyy"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The following is a slightly more modular approach which removes everything after the last `/` in the value and replaces it with whatever value the `newval` variable is set to on the `jq` command line:

```bsh
jq --arg newval 'yyy' '(.spec.template.spec.containers[].env[] | select(.name == "ISTIO_META_OWNER").value) |= sub("[^/]*$"; $newval)' file.json
```

Note that `yyy` in this command  automatically would be properly JSON encoded by `jq`.